# Looking for mysql rows between certain unix time stamps

Tags: mysql, unix

I am trying to write a mysql query that pulls in a unix timestamp converts it to %Y%m%d format then finds the rows between a certain date range. The query works until we get the WHERE clause.  I have no idea why it isn't working.  I was hoping some sql guru out here could help me.

Thanks,

Chris

```
SELECT 
            date_format(from_unixtime('timestamp'),'%Y%m%d') AS 'datecreated'
            ,`order_id`
            , `email`
            , `subtotal`
            , `shipping_cost`
            , `total`
            , `status`
        FROM
            `orders`
        WHERE 'datecreated' >= '20160501' AND 'datecreated' < '20160512'
```

Comment: You should show us the error

Comment: There is no error.  I am just not getting 0 returned rows with the where clause.

Comment: Yes, you should have an error, you cant use `datecreated` alias on the where

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, he's not using an alias — he intends to (which is also wrong as you point out), but he's written 'datecreated' as a string.  Sometimes MySQL's looseness with quotes is a gift, and sometimes not.

Comment: @pilcrow Ok I miss that, but when he fix the alias, then will get the error I mention :P   .... OP to be clear you should use back tick (fieldname)  `\`datecreated\`` not  single quote (strings) `'datecreated'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **CANT** use the alias on the where

Either you write the date_format function again

```
SELECT 
        date_format(from_unixtime('timestamp'),'%Y%m%d') AS `datecreated`
        ,`order_id`
        , `email`
        , `subtotal`
        , `shipping_cost`
        , `total`
        , `status`
    FROM
        `orders`
    WHERE date_format(from_unixtime('timestamp'),'%Y%m%d') >= '20160501' 
     AND  date_format(from_unixtime('timestamp'),'%Y%m%d') < '20160512'
```

Or create a sub query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        date_format(from_unixtime('timestamp'),'%Y%m%d') AS `datecreated`
        ,`order_id`
        , `email`
        , `subtotal`
        , `shipping_cost`
        , `total`
        , `status`
    FROM
        `orders`
     ) T
 WHERE `datecreated` >= '20160501' AND 'datecreated' < '20160512'
```

**EDIT:**

also fieldname use back thicks not single quotes

```
  `datecreated` field name
  'datecreated' string constant
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thanks!  I also learned something new on not using aliases with where clauses.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am trying to write a mysql query that pulls in a unix timestamp converts it to %Y%m%d format then finds the rows between a certain date range.*

You might be thinking through the problem backwards.  First find the right rows via WHERE, and then worry about formatting/converting the data in the result set:

```
SELECT date_format(from_unixtime('timestamp'),'%Y%m%d') AS "datecreated",
       ... other fields ...
  FROM "orders"
 WHERE "timestamp" >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01 00:00:00')
       AND
       "timestamp" <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-12 00:00:00')
```

As a bonus, the above can make use of an index on `"timestamp"`.

### Aside

In its default mode, MySQL allows several quoting styles and permits strings to be `"double quoted"` or `'single quoted'`, even though the former is the ANSI SQL standard for quoting *identifiers* (like column names).

While that's a convenience, I think it's more trouble than it's worth in cases like this.  Where you wrote `'col' > 'yyyymmdd'` you were comparing one *string* to another instead of the computed column you intended to compare.  (As mentioned in comments, that, too, would have failed, but your query didn't get that far.)

You might want to familiarize yourself with MySQL's [ANSI mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) which removes much of this ambiguity.  You'll appreciate the practice if you ever move to an RDBMS other than MySQL.

Comment: this answer is better than mine, because show a better practice on how set up the where clausule. Using index make big difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

change date format

```
SELECT 
            date_format(from_unixtime('timestamp'),'%Y%m%d') AS 'datecreated'
            ,`order_id`
            , `email`
            , `subtotal`
            , `shipping_cost`
            , `total`
            , `status`
        FROM
            `orders`
        WHERE from_unixtime('timestamp') between '2016-05-01' AND '2016-0512'
```